# Gridviews in TabControl losing binding on ActiveTabChanged

Tags: data-binding, gridview, tabcontrol

I have a ajax tab control with 7 tabs and a gridview in each tab. I have it set to autopostback and fill each gridview when that tab is selected. This all works fine. What I would like to be able to do is not fill a gridview if it has already been filled once, but each time I switch tabs the gridviews lose their binding and HAVE to be bound to their datasource again. Any ideas?

Comment: it depends on which event you bind your grid

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind all your grid of every tab in page load event of page in side

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
   Bindgrid();
   Bindgrid2();
   ....
}
```

Comment: So the viewstate doesn't hold on to the binding at all? I HAVE to rebind the gridview every time the page is posted back? Rebinding it each time a postback occurs seems to take several seconds for it to "refresh", and I didn't want my users to have to sit there for a few seconds while the thing reloaded.

Comment: if u use bindgrid inside ispostback then it will bind only one time not on every postback